# NodeJS capture/read output of process.stdout

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, stdout, stdin

I am trying to process the output of a specific function that uses process.stdout / process.stdin to print the commands results to the terminal. To be more specific, this Kubernetes function https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/src/exec.ts with this usage:

```
const exec = new k8s.Exec(kc);
exec.exec('default', 'nginx-4217019353-9gl4s', 'nginx', command,
    process.stdout, process.stderr, process.stdin,
    true /* tty */,
    (status) => {
        console.log('Exited with status:');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(status, null, 2));
    });
```

While the function above may print something like that to the terminal:

```
Everything is up.
Time running: 5min 23sec.

Exited with status:
{
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Success"
}
```

My goal is to capture

```
Everything is up.
Time running: 5min 23sec.
```

in a variable so that I can process it further.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Creating an own stream object instead of using the one from process / console works good.

```
var Stream = require('stream');
    
var ws = new Stream;
ws.writable = true;
ws.str = "";
ws.str = 0;

ws.string = function(){
  return ws.str;
}

ws.clearStr = function(){
  ws.str = "";
}

ws.write = function(buf) {
  ws.str += buf.toString();
  ws.bytes += buf.length;
}

ws.end = function(buf) {
   if(arguments.length) ws.write(buf);
   ws.writable = false;
}

async function kubeExec(ns, pod, container, cmd){
  ws.clearStr();
  ret = new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
    execV1Api.exec(ns,pod,container,cmd, ws, process.stderr , process.stdin,true /* tty */,
      async function(ret){
          if(ret.status == "Success"){
            resolve(ws.str);
          } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(status, null, 2));
          }
      });
  });

  return ret.then( (str) => { return str;} );
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

An year later, and I have this exact need, and still no viable solution to use the exec API to capture the `Writable` stream. The problem with this API is that the `Writable` is also async, so you'll need to wait for it to yield data. But you can't wait while calling the `exec.exec`, because the command won't be executed, and so you either end up with no data, or infinite loop.

The best solution I can come up with is to use another process to run the `kubectl exec` directly (e.g. if you're writing tests with cypress, use `cy.exec()` and then wait for the response). Below is a working solution for me:

```
// in this command, I count how many deadletter messages are there in the event storage
const podName = 'event-storage-8687775474-4snsc';
const command = `kubectl exec ${podName} -- wc -l deadletter.jsonl`;

cy.exec(command).then((response) => {
  const count = parseInt(response.stdout, 10);
  expect(count).to.equal(0); // verify that there are zero deadletter messages
});
```

It's worth nothing that you can combine this with other k8s client API, such as the `listNamespacedPod` to get the actual podName above at runtime, like this:

```
const kc = new KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();

const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(CoreV1Api);

k8sApi.listNamespacedPod(namespace).then((res) => {
  const list: V1PodList = res.body as V1PodList;

  const podName = list.items
    .filter((item) => item.metadata.name.startsWith('event-storage'))
    .map((item) => item.metadata.name)[0]; // [0] - assuming that there is only one such pod

  const command = `kubectl exec ${podName} -- wc -l deadletter.jsonl`;

  cy.exec(command).then((response) => {
    const count = parseInt(response.stdout, 10);
    expect(count).to.equal(0);
  });
});
```